# How to save a smaller file size, but keep high-res vector file for printing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize, file-size

I created a design on Illustrator using design elements from various vector sites my client and I bought. It’s a 30x50cm design on a paper wrapper. It’s nothing complicated (think patterns) but the file size is 140MB both in .ai and .pdf

I’ve got my artboard setup exactly the same size as the physial wrapper (30x50cm) and another artboard for the measurements of it.

Is there any way I could get this down to at least 25MB in .pdf? For context, his printer is in China and we could only send via e-mail—that’s what I’m told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you email a link to a site where the person can download the file?

Otherwise, you could export as a PDF, uncheck "Illustrator Capabilities", and change the image compression.

Comment: For context, I cannot send files via link on any file transfer service (Google Drive, Dropbox, NihaoCloud, Sendspace, WeTransfer, Firefox Send). But unchecking "Illustrator Capabilities" somehow reduced the file size to 23MB. Thank you so much.